# How to play multiple audio files on mysql database by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

this is my simple player here of which the link of the audio file is being pulled from the database (i store the music file name on the database), it plays only one song how can i tell it to continue playing let say 10 first songs ? here is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2,1;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>

<div class="col-md-4 player">
<div class="audio-player">
<audio id="audio-player"  controls="controls">
<source src="media/audio/<?php echo $row['audio_file']; ?>" 
type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>
</div>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#audio-player').mediaelementplayer({
alwaysShowControls: true,
    features: ['playpause','progress','volume'],
    audioVolume: 'horizontal',
    iPadUseNativeControls: true,
    iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
    AndroidUseNativeControls: true
  });
});
```

Comment: `Java !== JavaScript`

Comment: remove the LIMIT 2,1, or change it to LIMIT 10 from your sql statement. Does the page display multiple players?

Comment: Yes, when i put 10 or certain number of row it shows multiple players according to the number

Comment: OK. So if you select player #4 does the player work? If not then what does the console report. If it does then I can't see what the problem is. unless you want a single player looping through the pre-selected files.

Comment: jeff they all play, but it breaks my webpage and it becomes very hard for mobile users, i want it to play on the single player

Comment: That's a different matter. Fetch you files and store the values into a JavaScript array. Then with the single player point to the file. Using JavaScript you can tell whether or not the file is still playing. If not then load the next file and off you go again. Here is a link with some audio libraries that might be useful: https://www.egrappler.com/wonderful-javascript-audio-libraries-for-developers/

Comment: thank you let me check there

Comment: I embedded Jplayer,